# Need optimization for SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new in SQL and writing query which gives me 'users' who have supervisor role

And here is the query I wrote. Please give me hints to optimazie it.

```
  select t.* from Adm_Users t where t.User_Id member of v_active_users 
and exists (
       select Ur.User_Id from Adm_User_Roles Ur where Ur.Role_Id = Adm_Util.c_Ri_Supervisor       and ur.user_id=t.user_id
)
```

Comment: for optimisation http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the best place

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар I agree for optimization of a working code we go for codereview. But here the code snippet is not a complete one and its what used tried to build. So this should not be migrated

Comment: @realspirituals i agree with you . if is not complete it should not be migrated.i thought OP was asking for optimization of working sql query

Comment: The query is syntactically incorrect.  The table alias `Adm_Util` has no reference.  You can't optimize a non-working query.

Comment: This isn't a plsql problem but there are likely to be lots of optimizations if the schema queried is known... even more if the design has not been finalized.